# Tourism - Canadian Computing Contest, Optimization Issues

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

Question 4 from CCC 2019

Problem Description
You are planning a trip to visit N tourist attractions. The attractions are numbered from 1 to N and
must be visited in this order. You can visit at most K attractions per day, and want to plan the trip
to take the fewest number of days as possible.
Under these constraints, you want to find a schedule that has a nice balance between the attractions
visited each day. To be precise, we assign a score ai
to attraction i. Given a schedule, each day is
given a score equal to the maximum score of all attractions visited that day. Finally, the scores of
each day are summed to give the total score of the schedule. What is the maximum possible total
score of the schedule, using the fewest days possible?
Input Specification
The first line contains two space-separated integers N and K (1 ≤ K ≤ N ≤ 10^6
).
The next line contains N space separated integers ai (1 ≤ ai ≤ 10^9
).
For 3 of the 15 available marks, 2K ≥ N.
For an additional 3 of the 15 available marks, K ≤ 100 and N ≤ 10^5
.
Output Specification
Output a single integer, the maximum possible total score.
Sample Input
5 3
2 5 7 1 4
Output for Sample Input
12
Explanation of Output for Sample Input
We need to have at least two days to visit all the attractions, since we cannot visit all attractions in
one day.
Visiting the first two attractions on day 1 will give a score of 5, and visiting the last three attractions
on day 2 will give a score of 7, for a total score of 12.
Visiting three attractions on day 1, and two attractions on day 2, which is the only possibility to
visit in the fewest number of days possible, would yield a total score of 7 + 4 = 11.

My approach
Using recursion go through the initial attractions then send in the part for the second day and find the highest score in each recursion

```py
def scores(things, att, days):
    minper = attractions(att,row1[1])

    if att <= 0:
        return 0, False
    if days > minday:
        return 0, True
    else:
        maxscore = 0
        for y in range(minper,row1[1]+1):
            score, more = scores(things[y:],att-y,days+ 1)
            if not(more):
                score += max(things[:y+1])
            if score >= maxscore:
                maxscore = score
        return maxscore, False

def attractions(attr,maxper):
    if (attr % maxper) == 0 and attr > 0:
        return maxper
    return (attr % maxper)

row1=(input()).split(" ")
places=(input()).split(" ")

for x in range(len(row1)):
    row1[x] = int(row1[x])

for x in range(len(places)):
    places[x] = int(places[x])

if (row1[0]/row1[1])%1 == 0:
    minday = int(row1[0]/row1[1])

else:
    minday =(row1[0]//row1[1]) + 1

if minday !=1:
    maxscore = 0
    for x in range(attractions(row1[0],row1[1]),row1[1]+1):
        score, more = scores(places[x:],row1[0]-x,1)
        if not(more):
            score += max(places[:x])
        if score >= maxscore:
            maxscore = score
    print(maxscore)
else:
    print(max(places))
```

The test cases for the problems include numbers where N is 1000000 and K is 999999 so that means the possible trips per day for the 2 days (minimum days), are 1,999999 2,999998 ... 999998,2 999999,1, which takes too long for this approach, and another case, for example, N = 51, K = 10, so it can be 10,10,10,10,10,1 or 10,1,10,10,10,10 or it can also be 9,9,9,9,9,6 and more but it covers every permutation of the numbers that add up to the min days. How do I optimize this better, or is there a better approach to do it within the 1 sec time.

Comment: Since this is a contest question, I will not post an answer but give a hint: If we define the function `S(i, a)` to be the maximum total score that you can achieve after `i` days using attractions up to `a`, how can you calculate that value using previous values in a dynamic programming fashion?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would suggest (a naive approach):

- The shortest number of days (D) will be (N-1)//K+1
- If N is a multiple of D, then you have only one way to organize the vacation in D days.
- Otherwise, start out with the first D-1 days visiting K attractions and the last day visiting the remaining ones (R) = N-K*(D-1)
- Hold this in a base array of number of attractions where positions represent the days
- Then, you only need to distribute K-R attractions across the first D-1 days, swapping a number of attractions with the last day.
- Using a brute force approach, you will loop from 1 to K-R for the number of attractions to swap (S).
- Within that loop you will need to expand combinations of S days out of the first D-1 days with possible repetitions of the same day. (Python's itertools module has a function that does that: combinations_with_replacement)
- For each of these combinations, swap the corresponding attraction counts from a copy of the base array, compute and track the total of maximum ratings for that vacation plan.
- Time should be D*[1 + Cr(D-1,2) + Cr(D-1,3) + ... Cr(D-1,S)],  where Cr(n,r) is combinations of r in n with repetitions: (r+n-1)!/(r!(n-1)!)

**Special case: 2K > N (minimum days = 2)**

When there are only two vacation days, the algorithm can be greatly simplified by considering that the two days have a common overlap where attractions could be seen on either day.  There are also leading attractions that must be seen on the first day and tailing attractions that must be seen on the second day.  So we are looking for the top 2 attraction between the leading, tailing and common groups.  The leading and tailing groups can have no more than one "top attraction" each and the common group can have up to two.

So there are only 4 ways the top 2 attractions can be distributed between the three groups:

```
[---lead---][---common---][---tail---]
    X             X                    
                  X X             
                  X            X
    X                          X
```

Taking the top 2 between max(lead), max(tail) and top2 of common will give us the best possible combination as illustrated here with 4 simulated values.

```
    MAX         TOP 2         MAX         TOP 2       Trip
[---lead---][---common---][---tail---]    of groups   TOTAL
    10          20,30         40          30,40       70
    10          20,40         30          30,40       70
    10          30,40         20          30,40       70
    20          10,30         40          30,40       70
    20          10,40         30          30,40       70
    20          30,40         10          30,40       70
    30          10,20         40          30,40       70
    30          10,40         20          30,40       70
    30          20,40         10          30,40       70
    40          10,20         30          30,40       70
    40          10,30         20          30,40       70
    40          20,30         10          30,40       70
```

- Determine the minimum visit count (MV) = N % K
- The first and last MV visits will necessarily be part of the first and second day (respectively)
- These will be identified as leading visits (LV) and tailing visits (TV)
- Find the top two scores in the common visits (CV) from LV+1 ... N-TV inclusively (TopCommon1, TopCommon2)
- Find the top attraction for the leading and trailing visits (LV->LT, TopLead -> TopTail)
- Find the top 2 out of TopLead, TopCommon1, TopCommon2, TopTail
- Add them together to obtain the total score for the trip

**Better algorithm for other cases**

To improve on the above brute force, we could compute partial trip scores for each attraction when it is the first one of the day.  This can be worked out incrementally from last to first.  Then the trip score of the first attraction is the answer.

- Start from the last attraction and work backward to the first one (AN = attraction number)
- Determine how many attractions remain (including this one): (RA) = N - AN + 1
- determine the number of days for the RA attractions (RD) = (RA-1)/K+1
- Determine the minimum visits that need to be done on that day (MV) = RA - K*(RD-1)
- Possible visits on that day will range from MV to K.
- For each visit count (VC) in this range compute the maximum visit score (MS) for attractions in the range (current day...+VC).
- The next attraction will be the first one of the next day
- Since we've already computed the trip total for visits starting at that attraction we simply need to use that computed value and add the current day's best attraction (MS)

*Note that this can be further optimized by performing simpler calculations for edge cases such as the first and last visits within the "minimum visit" range.  I think this would only be significant for cases where K is very large (yet no larger than N/2) and N mod K is close to K*

Comment: So, I have tried a method using the permutations of the combinations of amount of attractions per day, the problem that I find hardest to face is the fact that brute forcing it requires too much time when days start increasing. Your solution would work but not within the 1 sec which it is required to run in, Is there anyway that this can be done in a non brute force way?

Comment: Have you tried to make the extra days distribution into a recursion with memoizing.  It is likely that there are tons of redundant distributions of extra days that are the same for a given combination of S and days X to D-1.  Python has a nice decorator called lru_cache in the functools module that is great to add memoizing to existing functions.